# Sort Two Randoms Lists So They Match

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, match

I have one sheet with four cols of data. Col A and Col G display company names.

The data that is located on the same row, in cols A and G, do not match.

After sorting / alphabetizing Col A and Col G I need to have the data match on the same row. Col B data goes with data in Col A ... Col H data goes with data in Col G.

Some of the rows will match after running a macro ... most will likely not match and will require blank rows between the non-matches

Your assistance for a VBA macro is greatly appreciated. I have no idea how to accomplish this. Thank you.

Download workbook : [Download](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/CrJbwvdwbk8wdM2kAWegZnu2XAuOaE0CdnJKdMoJwJD)

Comment: In 2018 you received code to SORT some columns.  Just apply that to each range  A:B  and  G:H.  Then from first data row to last (of each pair of columns), do your matching and insert a line.  Please show your sample code and what your problem(s) are.

Comment: " I have no idea how to accomplish this. Thank you."  (As was posted previously.)  Manually sorting and matching both columns is tedious and tiresome. Especially when there are thousands of rows of data.